# Issue with regex expression in vim

Tags: html, css, regex, vim

I have this string:

```
<img src="<?php echo CDN(); ?>images/logo.png" style="outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: transparent;text-align: center;" />
```

Please don't point to inline styling. I know it's a mess. Just dealing with some legacy code.

I need to convert `<?php echo CDN(); ?>images/logo.png"` string to: `<?php echo CDN('images/logo.png'); ?>images/logo.png"`. I am trying to make a regex for it using vim since there are multiple files. This is the regex that I have made:

`:%s/"<?php echo CDN(); ?>\(.*\)"/"<?php echo CDN('\1'); ?>\1"/g`

But the output that I get is this:

```
<img src="<?php echo CDN('images/logo.png" style="outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: transparent;text-align: center;'); ?>images/logo.png" style="outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; margin-bottom: 0; margin-left: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 0; border-top-width: 0; border-right-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; background-color: transparent;text-align: center;" />
```

The regex doesn't end at `logo.png"` but goes on to take everything after `"` in consideration as well. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the regex?

**EDIT**

Thanks all for the answer. It worked. Now I am trying to write a sed regex so that I could apply this regex to every file. I got this:

`cat test.php | sed -r 's/"<?php echo CDN\(\); ?>(.*)"/"<?php echo CDN\(\1\); ?>\1"/g'`

As you might have guessed, it breaks. It works with `<?php echo CDN\(\)` but stops working the moment I add `?>`. I don't know why.

**Further edit**
My mistake. here is the sed pattern: `sed -r 's/"<\?php echo CDN\(\); \?>([^"]*)"/"<\?php echo CDN\("\1"\); \?>\1"/g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.*?` instead of `.*` - this makes the quantifier lazy so it stops matching at the first quote. Alternatively, use `[^"]*` to explicitly match non-quote characters.

Comment: @Kent Ah... sorry! I'm not a vim user, but I sort of assumed it'd follow the same basic syntax... then again I made that assumption with MySQL `REGEXP` before learning that word boundaries, for some unfathomable reason, are `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` there...

Comment: .*? caused 'No match found' error. [^"]* however worked. Thanks a ton! I tried the same with .*\? but again ended up with 'No match found' error.

Answer (score 5):

You need *non-greedy matching*; i.e. use `.\{-}` (Vim's syntax for "0 or more, as few as possible", what's often written `.*?` in other regular expression dialects) instead of `.*`.

Since double quotes cannot be contained, you can further restrict this by disallowing the double quote `[^"]` instead of matching all kinds of characters (`.`); with this, you can still safely use the greedy multiplier `[^"]*`:

```
:%s/"<?php echo CDN(); ?>\([^"]*\)"/"<?php echo CDN('\1'); ?>\1"/g
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see for yourself what the problem is if you test the search pattern before using it in the `:s` command.  If you have not already done so, `:set hls` and then `/"<?php echo CDN(); ?>\(.*\)"`.  Have fun banging on the <kbd>n</kbd> key.

You might find that your pattern misses some cases; perhaps you will have to replace  (single space) with `\s\+`, for example.

Once you have the right pattern, you can use `:s//<replacement>` to use it by default, or (if you want to save it in your command history) use `<C-R>/` to insert the pattern on the command line.

```
:help :s
:help c_CTRL-R
```